# How to share a dimension

Tags: ssas

For some reason, I am having a mental block trying to figure out how dimensions get associated with cubes, and why dimensions can't all just be used in any number of cubes.  (I'm working on a MS SSAS project.)

In most cases, shouldn't there be only one time dimension?  Is there a simple way to use it with multiple cubes?

Edit: For now I'm going to start using the New Linked Object wizard.  If someone could confirm that this is the right approach I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of SSAS are you using? In 2008, you can create multiple dimensions and multiple cubes in each projects, and you can use dimensions in as many cubes as you want.

If I remember right, you were able to do that as well in 2005.

Comment: Dominic, I figured it out since I posted this two months ago, and I'm embarrassed about asking such a silly question.  I think I was trying to add the dimension directly in the cube, when I should have added the table directly in the DSV first.  I was really new to SSAS at the time.  Thanks.