# How do I add an existing database dimension to a second SSAS cube?

Tags: ssas

Long-time SQL Server relational DBA building my second-ever cube in my first-ever SSAS database (using 2008 R2).

I am trying to add to that second cube a database dimension already associated with the first cube.  No matter how I launch it, the Add Cube Dimension dialog lists only the dimensions that have already been associated with the second cube, not the one I want (nor any others) already associated with the first cube.  Based on multiple web-search results, I was under the impression that database dimensions are designed to be added to multiple cubes within the same database, and that this should be easy.  What am I missing?

I believe what I'm asking is nearly identical to the question posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640326/how-to-share-a-dimension), but I haven't had the same epiphany that the original poster did.  The table behind the dimension I want is already in the DSV.

Comment: So you have a dimension object listed in the "Dimensions" folder in Solution Explorer, and when you click in the bottom left corner of the Cube Designer/Cube Structure tab of your cube, you do not see the dimension object there?

Comment: Looks like my epiphanies are just a little slow.  It turns out that the root of my issue was that I had created a second DSV to use with the second cube, adding only the new tables to it that I needed for the new cube and building dimensions for the new cube based on the tables in the new DSV.  I ended up dropping thew new cube and the new DSV; adding the tables I needed to my original DSV; building my new dimensions against the new tables in the original DSV; and rebuilding the new cube against dimensions that were all built against tables in the original (and only) DSV.

Comment: Please change your comments to answer and mark it as correct answer if you have resolved the issue.